# What's wrong with this sentence: "Travelling by train is healthier and safer while enhancing the passengers' comfort."

Tags: sentence-construction

> Travelling by train is healthier and safer while enhancing the passengers' comfort.

The intended meaning is that train travel is "healthier, safer, and more comfortable" than travel by car. Obviously the "while enhancing" phrase is ungrammatical, but why?

Other examples:

- *Cake is fun and delicious while making parties more festive.*
- *Joan is smart and friendly while never showing up to work late.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Travelling by train is healthier and safer while enhancing the passengers' comfort.

In terms of usage of the word "[while](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/while)" your phrase can mean two things:

1. During the process of enhancing* (rather unidiomatic in my opinion) the comfort of passengers the action of travelling by train is healthier and safer. - which is absurd in terms of logic.
2. A contrast of statements, but I can not get the grip of grammar used here and hence I can conclude that there is a mistake. You can not substitute "while" for "but", "compared to", "compared with the fact that", "despite the fact that" or "although" in this particular example without the necessity to change the wording and structure of this sentence.

The correct way to explain the correct meaning could be:

- Travelling by train is healthier and safer while also providing comfort for passengers. - If we are speaking of consequent ideas and not contrasting ones.

Comment: Good answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The better sentence can be:

> Travelling by train is healthier and safer, while it enhances passengers' comfort.

Comment: Thank you, but I disagree. That sentence does not strike me as proper English. The correct way to express the thought is: "Traveling by train is healthier, safer, and more comfortable." If you wanted to set off the last point, you could say: ". . . is not only healthier and safer but also more comfortable." I know the right constructions; I just want to know the grammatical explanation for the error so that I can explain it to my students.

Comment: It is not so much that the sentence is ungrammatical, the problem is that it is ambiguous. I agree with Marvi Garg's. answer.